# CSS complex selector: select the second child of a div item

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm try to write a complex selector for css3.
I need to select the second div of a child of a an item:
here the html code for my test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div.main > div:nth-child(3) {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        -> 1-level
        <div>
            -----> 2-level
            <div>--------> 3-level BAR</div>
            <div>--------> 3-level FOO</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i need to select the 3-level FOO ! but i can't append another class other .main class
I'm trying with 'div.main > div:nth-child(3)' without any success....
here a jsfiddle with this code.
http://jsfiddle.net/vwwuuhao/1/

Comment: .main > div > div:nth-child(2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you missunderstood the way [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) works. It is used to select the nth-child of an element and not the "nth-level-child".

Your selector should look like this :

```
.main > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
.main > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    -> 1-level
    <div>
      -----> 2-level
      <div>--------> 3-level BAR</div>
      <div>--------> 3-level FOO</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
div.main > div > div:last-child {/*or use div:nth-child(2)*/
            display: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`div:nth-child(3)` is the third sibling child. You are looking for:

```
//         vvv — this is 2nd level
//               vvv — this is 2nd level
//                            vvv FOO is a second sibling
div.main > div > div:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use div:nth-of-type(x)

sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/L6xkanrm/1/

eg:
if you want to select the SECOND div inside another div, use:

```
div div:nth-of-type(2) {
        display: none;
}
```